# How to avoid dynamic assertion in wrapper functions?

Tags: go, reflection, wrapper, assertion

In the simplified code example below, we perform tens of different API calls using the Go library from our vendor.

Vendor library provides us with a definition of API call bodies:

```
// body of api call A
type requestBodyA struct {
    aa string
    bb int32
}

// body of api call B
type requestBodyB struct {
    id string
}
```

And with functions which performs the calls for us:

```
// fn performs api call A
func callCreateA(body requestBodyA) {
    fmt.Println("Value of body is: ", body)
    // makes api call using body requestBodyA
}

// fn performs api call B
func callCreateB(body requestBodyB) {
    fmt.Println("Value of body is: ", body)
    // makes another api call using body requestBodyB
}
```

We use those to create our own CRUD functions, where we read config files and perform create/read/update/delete calls:

```
func createA() {
    bodyA := requestBodyA{
        aa: "asdasfsd",
        bb: 15,
    }

    // api retry loop
    for i := 1; i <= 3; i++ {
        // do some pre-checks (generic)

        callCreateA(bodyA)

        // check for errors (generic)
        // check if error is recoverable (generic)
        // if not return error (generic)
        // if yes use the for loop and try the call again in 1,2,3,5,8,13, .. seconds (generic)
    }
}

func createB() {
    bodyB := requestBodyB{
        id: "someUniqueId",
    }
    for i := 1; i <= 3; i++ {
        // do some pre-checks (generic)

        callCreateB(bodyB)

        // check for errors (generic)
        // check if error is recoverable (generic)
        // if not return error (generic)
        // if yes use the for loop and try the call again in 1,2,3,5,8,13, .. seconds (generic)
    }
}
```

As you can see in functions `createA`, `createB` we repeat a lot of generic code (pre-checks, error handling, retry loop and lot more) in every CRUD fn we create. As we're dealing with 30+ resources and each have their own create, read, update, destroy API call function, we have the same code copied 100+ times.

I'd like to move all the generic stuff to some genericApiCaller() and give it the call body as one param and name or a pointer to the API call function as a second param.

Problem 1: `callCreateA` and `callCreateB` needs the "body" of different types. It would be way easier if they consume interface{}, but these functions are coming from vendor SDK and it would not be smart to modify them (update reasons, etc). How to assert "body interface{}" of genericApiCaller() to "body requestBodyA" or "body requestBodyB" dynamically? Runtime assertion is not possible in Go, but I didn't find any nice solution for it.

Problem2: How to pass functions with different kinds of parameters as a parameter to genericApiCaller()?

https://play.golang.org/p/incf-NEaSJ3

Comment: I would do the reverse. Move each block of generic code to its own function that can be called from each of the `createA`, `createB`, etc functions.

Comment: The retry can also be in its own function very easily by writing a function that takes a function as a parameter and retries it as long as e.g. the function returns a non-nil error.

Comment: @JakubP Have you considered using an interface? i.e. something like this: https://play.golang.org/p/P3ocyHpfvBr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to extend vendor types to use something like CallCreate interface:

```
type myBodyA requestBodyA
func (b myBodyA) CallCreate() {
    callCreateA((requestBodyA)(b))
}

type myBodyB requestBodyB
func (b myBodyB) CallCreate() {
    callCreateB((requestBodyB)(b))
}

type CallCreate interface {
    CallCreate()
}

func main() {
    var ifs CallCreate
    ifs = myBodyA{
        aa: "aa",
        bb: 15,
    }
    for i := 1; i <= 3; i++ {
        ifs.CallCreate()
    }
    ifs = myBodyB{
        id: "someUniqueId",
    }
    for i := 1; i <= 3; i++ {
        ifs.CallCreate()
    }
```

You can also use something like

```
func genericApiCall(api,body interface{}) {
    av := reflect.ValueOf(api)
    av.Call([]reflect.Value{reflect.ValueOf(body)})
}

func main() {
    bodyA := requestBodyA{
        aa: "asdasfsd",
        bb: 15,
    }
    genericApiCall(callCreateA,bodyA)
    bodyB := requestBodyB{
        id: "someUniqueId",
    }
    genericApiCall(callCreateB,bodyB)
}
```

However, in my view, the second is not so elegant.